# Can I get TeamCity agents to make registry settings available as agent properties?

Tags: teamcity

We recently added a new TeamCity build agent. Because it doesn't have ASP.NET MVC 3 installed, several of our builds fail on that agent.

Of course, I *could* install MVC 3 on the agent, but I'd like something more intelligent.

Obviously, I could also add an agent property to the agent configuration file, and specify it as a dependency, but that'd involve updating 14 different agents.

Is there any way that I can get the TeamCity agent to discover (probably via the registry) whether something is installed or not? Is there any way to configure this centrally?

We're currently using TeamCity 6.5.6, but we'll be upgrading to 7.x shortly, if that'd help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have related issue in our tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-13126
An agent side plugin could be written to do something like this. You can find some points how to implement this plugin in the issue.